# Problem with chapter's name on bybliography

Tags: bibtex

So guys,

there is a template of Latex in my university. Problem is, I gotta change the title of the chapter of References (bybliography). So, the template is here http://www.puc-rio.br/ensinopesq/ccpg/download/ThesisPUC-1.0.2%20.zip and the documentation is here http://www.puc-rio.br/ensinopesq/ccpg/download/ThesisPUC.pdf.

Inside of the template, there is a tiny example which I can use to show the problem I'm having.

tiny.tex has the follow:

```
\documentclass[phd]{ThesisPUC}
...
\begin{document}
...
\input{chapter-1}
...
\arial
\bibliography{tiny}
\end{document}
```

And tiny.bib has the references, and ThesisPUC.cls has:

```
...
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Referências Bibliográficas}%
\bibliographystyle{ThesisPUC}%
\renewcommand{\key}[1]{#1. }
\special{ pdf: docinfo << /Author (\puc@author) /Title (\puc@title) /Keywords (\puc@keywords) >> }%
}
```

So, I changed that `{Referências Bibliográficas}` for `{Trying other name}`
The thing is, "other name" has to be all lowercase. BUT when I do that, the name never change!

I tried many commands, but nothing worked. So, checking the ThesisPUC.bst file, it has:

```
...
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
'skip$
{ preamble$ write$ newline$ }
if$
"\begin{thebibliography}{" longest.label * "} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname} \arial\markboth{\bibname}{\bibname} " * write$ newline$
}
...
```

So, I can see the name I created on TOC and on the page mark, but never on the Chapter name correctly..

Can someone please help me!? **I need a chapter called "Trying other name" with all references!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your document class is loading the `babel` package with the `main=brazil` option loaded. This option enables various language specific things such as changing the bibliography name. Then, `ThesisPUC` also sets this name to the same value.

The fact that redefining `\bibname` in `ThesisPUC.cls` doesn't have any effect is probably caused by `babel` also using the `\AtBeginDocument` hook (which is executed somewhere inside of `\begin{document}`) to change the definition. But here the `babel` definition seems to be executed *after* the one in `ThesisPUC.cls`.

As a solution (untested), don't use the `\AtBeginDocument` hook to change `\bibname` but put that redefinition directly in the body of your document:

```
\documentclass[phd]{ThesisPUC}
...
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Some other name}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx man! It worked! =)